# How to interpret Bitbucket Commit Graph's visualization?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am currently using **Bitbucket's** commit graph visualization to understand my commit history and it's pretty confusing as the left most branch does not correspond to the `develop`(the branch I have selected in the drop down list) in some cases.

[image: commit history of my code]

In contrast, I have checked the command `git log --graph --oneline --all` (after `git checkout develop`) and the output given by it is what I was expecting. The left most branch indicated `develop` and it was easier for me to understand all the `merges` to the branch I want to consider, which is `develop` in this case.

How should I interpret Bitbucket commit graph's visualization? I think it's NOT equivalent to the command `git log --graph --oneline --all`? What is it equivalent to?

Comment: Just curious: what does `git log --graph --oneline --all origin/develop` produce to the terminal so that you think they both output different graphs?

Comment: It's a commit graph no?

Answer (score 2):

I will share with you a command that is useful for me to draw a similar bitbucket diagram in my Command Line Interface.

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --all
```

You also can add a git alias adding the following config on `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --all
```

This way running `git lol` command you also can quickly see a similar graph.

I hope it may help you!